# Should I indent subheadings in HTML 5?

Tags: indentation

**Hello everyone! I'm learning HTML 5 and I have a simple question..
Should be subheadings be indented? Since h2 is subheading of h1, so, should I indent h2?
For example:

```
<h1>My blog</h1>
  <h2>Photos</h2>
    <h3>My cat</h3>
    <h3>My dog</h3>
```

Comment: Up to you … you can do that, if it helps yourself in working with your code. The browser that’s eventually going to display this, doesn’t care about that. (And if it was part of any bigger CMS or other such system, chances are the HTML output might get “minified” before actually being send to the client anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a personal preference, but no. They are not nested so shouldn't be indented.

Answer (score 0):

No, only tag *content* should be indented, e.g.,

```
<h1>
  My Blog
</h1>
```

Or:

```
<h1>
  My Blog
  <strong>Something else</strong>
</h1>
```

Indentation should show DOM structure.

This is, of course, opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately up to you, as the browser doesn't care how you indent your code. However, typically only if tags are nested will they be indented. Example,

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<h2>This is an example</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>A cool dude</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sally</td>
    <td>A cool gal</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```